# loadMovie doesn't work on my server

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a flash swf file which I don't want people to be able to download and decompile it . my first solution was to load this swf file in another swf file and put the container swf file in my site . but something's wrong . when I load my swf file in another swf file using :
myloader.loadMovie("myswffile.swf"); 
it works fine in my local computer but when I load these two swf files to my server and try to use them there , it doesn't work . 
anyone has any idea about it?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have problems with crossdomain.xml file that tells the Flash is the server resources could be loaded from a specific URL.

http://wiki.flash-ripper.com/?title=Crossdomain.xml